# How to get Picasa/Google+ shared photo's URL quickly from Android mobile device?

Tags: photos, google-plus, picasa, url

My sister doesn't use Google+ so it is quite hard for me to share an individual photo of my Picasa album with her.

Currently I can only do that from a PC - opening picasa web album site, open the album, select the need-to-share image, then get the shared link from the box on the right.

I cannot quickly do this from my Google Samsung Nexus phone since the mobile version of Picasa web does not have get shared link like the PC version.

How can I get shared/embedded link of that photo the quickest way?

[image]